# Modules and Variables carrying over tfvar values

Tags: terraform

I am fairly new to TF and I have written some basic code. Enough to get a vpc up and running and add some subnets and deploy a simple ec2. I am starting to get to the point of wanting to use modules. I struggle with the "keeping generic" thing so I can reuse them over and over. I do not understand how values get passed into modules. For instance I have a module that deploys a vpc, within the same project I have a module that deploys a vpc endpoint. The questions becomes how do i get the value of the vpc_id created with vpc module into the vpc endpoint module? Does anyone have an example of this?

main.tf

```
    provider "aws" {
    region = var.aws_region
    }

    /*Module for VPC creation*/
    module "vpc" {
    source                  = "./modules/vpc"
    vpc_cidr                = var.vpc_cidr
    environment             = var.environment
    tnt_public_subnets_cidr = var.tnt_public_subnets_cidr
    availability_zones      = var.availability_zones

    }

    /*Module for EC2 Webserver creation*/
    module "webserver" {
    source      = "./modules/ec2/webserver"
    count       = var.instance_count
    environment = var.environment
    subnet_id   = module.vpc.tnt_public_subnets_cidr.id
    }

    /*Module for VPC endpoint creation*/
    module "s3-vpce"{
    source = "git::https://github.com/tn-sts-cloudtn/sts-terraform- 
    modules.git//s3-vpce-module/modules//s3-vpce"
    vpc_id    = module.vpc.vpc_id
  
    }
```

VPC Module TF File:

```
/*==== The VPC ======*/
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block           = var.vpc_cidr
  assign_generated_ipv6_cidr_block = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support   = true
  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.environment}_vpc"
    Environment = var.environment
  }
}

/*==== Internet Gateway for Public Subnets ======*/

/* Internet gateway for the public subnet */
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.environment}_igw"
    Environment = var.environment
  }
}


/* Elastic IP for NAT 
resource "aws_eip" "instance_eip" {
  count = 1
  vpc        = true
  depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.tnt_igw]
    tags ={
      Name = "sts_net_infra-mgmt_eip${count.index + 1}"
      Environment = var.environment
    }
}*/

/* Public subnet */
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnets_cidr" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  count             = length(var.availability_zones)
  cidr_block        = var.public_subnets_cidr [count.index]
  availability_zone = element(var.availability_zones, count.index)
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
   tags ={
      Name = "${var.environment}_mgmt_subnet_${count.index + 1}"
      Environment = var.environment
    }
}
/* Private subnet 
resource "aws_subnet" "tnt_private_subnet" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.tnt_vpc.id
  count                   = length(var.tnt_private_subnets_cidr)
  cidr_block        = var.tnt_public_subnets_cidr [count.index]
  availability_zone = element(var.availability_zones, count.index)
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  tags = {
    #Name        = var.environment-private-subnet
    Environment = var.environment
  }
*/

/* Routing table for private subnet 
resource "aws_route_table" "tnt_private_rtb" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.tnt_vpc.id
  tags = {
    Name        = var.environment_private_route_table
    Environment = var.environment
  }
}*/


/* Routing table for public subnet */
resource "aws_route_table" "public_rtb" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.environment}_public_route_table"
    Environment = var.environment
  }
}

resource "aws_route" "public_internet_gateway" {
  route_table_id         = aws_route_table.public_rtb.id
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  gateway_id             = aws_internet_gateway.igw.id
}

/* Route table associations */
resource "aws_route_table_association" "public" {
  count          = length(var.public_subnets_cidr)
  subnet_id      = element(aws_subnet.public_subnets_cidr.*.id, count.index)
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public_rtb.id

}
```

So I need to output the VPC ID for the VPC endpoint, so I tried to use an output.

output.tf

```
    output "vpc_cidr" {
    value = aws_vpc.tnt_vpc.id
}

output "tnt_public_subnets_cidr"{
    value = aws_subnet.tnt_public_subnets_cidr.*.id
}
output "vpc_id" {
  description = "The ID of the VPC"
  value       = aws_vpc.vpc.id
}

output "vpc_arn" {
  description = "The ARN of the VPC"
  value       = concat(aws_vpc.tnt_vpc.*.arn, [""])[0]
}
```

I know I am doing it incorrectly, but I am struggling to understand how outputs flow from module to module.

Comment: If you posted example code in your question, you have better chances of finding answers with examples. That said, have a look at [outputs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/outputs.html), you can reuse the output of a module in another module.

Comment: What `.tf` files do you have in `./modules/vpc`?

Comment: main, output, variables

Comment: Looking at the project structure and example code, seems you just need to use `module.vpc.vpc_id` in the other modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one moule output into onether module by defining output in each module.